# Routind Master-Detail Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, master-detail, laravel-routing

good morning,

someone who can help me, I need to create a route between father son model to model, leading to the url the id of the parent, which is called Master-Detail.

My model Detail Inventory:

```
    return $this->hasMany('Inventory');
```

My model Master Dependence:

```
    return $this->belongsTo('Dependence', 'dependece_id', 'id');
```

I want something like this:

localhost:8000/dependences/25/inventories

Thank you for your cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('dependencies/{id}/inventories', function($dependencyId)
{
    $dependency = Dependency::findOrFail($dependencyId);
    dd($dependency->integory->toArray());
});
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance, I am very new to the subject of the framework,

as I supposed to create the url in the index view Dependence, for this leads me to the index view inventory

Thank you

Comment: please who can give me a help, I see no reason to go out